# Псевдоэлемент по всей длине текста

Tags: css

Добрый день.
Есть заголовок, для которого нужно сделать заднюю черту, как показано на изображении.

[image: Пример заголовка]

Заголовки есть и по несколько строк, что по большому счету и является проблемой.
Было предложение сделать данное подчеркивание псевдоэлементом, но так и получилось добиться того, чтобы при переносе строки все работало корректно.
Есть ли решение данной задачи?

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
span {
  font-size: 2em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 50%, lightgreen 50%);
  }
```

```html
<span>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </span>
```